# Can't install Magento 2 via composer on Windows 10

Tags: magento2, installation, composer, windows10

I try to install magento 2 via composer.

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .
```

But I get "out of memory". I have 16 GB RAM.

So I restarted windows and tried again directly after restart without any programs open, but it still throws this error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 64 bytes) in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Rule2Literals.php
>   on line 53
>
> Check
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors
>   for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this command

> php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/
>   magento/project-community-edition --ignore-platform-reqs .

usually the path of composer is here:

```
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

If you are having problems with composer path , run the command below to find which path is the composer :

```
which composer
```

In your case should be :

> php -d memory_limit=-1 /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer
>   create-project --repository=repo.magento.com
>   magento/project-community-edition --ignore-platform-reqs .

Comment: I guess composer does not work with windows. I get `Could not open input file: C:/Program Files/Git/usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: upgraded my answer

Comment: `which composer` shows `/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer`

Comment: try to replace this /usr/local/bin/composer with this /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer

Comment: Im not sure where to find `/usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: try to run this : php -d memory_limit=-1  /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition --ignore-platform-reqs .

Comment: Did it worked @Black ?

Comment: No, but thanks for your attempt. I will do It in linux. I get `Could not open input file: /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer`

Comment: ok let me know if you got any other issues